# MSVC 2010 and MSVC 2012 are not works together

Tags: visual-c++

I have come accross following situation:

1. I had MSVC 2012 express and pro  edition in my windows 8 machine. My application build and run was working fine. Now I have installed MSVC 2010 express edition. My application build works. However it crashes duing run.
2. I had MSVC 2010 express and pro  edition in my windows 7 machine. My application build and run was working fine. Now I have installed MSVC 2012 express edition. My application build works. However it crashes duing run.

I am using qt 5.0.2 64 and 32 bit creator to build and run my application.

My question is whether MSVC 2010 and MSVC 2012 are not works together in a single machine?

Will they replace older version exe/dlls or will they conflict each other?

Is there any solution/fix without removing MSVC 2010 and MSVC 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [order of installation is important](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) - you *can* use VS2010 and VS2012 together (I do) but you must install VS2010 *first*.

Simply reinstall VS2012 and you should be ok, although you may need to use the Windows SDK registration utility after installing VS2012 to make sure that VS2010 is directed to the Windows 7 SDK.

Comment: Thank you. This link helped. I have uninstalled MSVC 2010. Now my application runs correctly using MSVC 2012.

Comment: The real issue was with DLL path mismatch. Fixing DLL paths resolved the issue.